# docker backup on production DB

Tags: docker, backup, restore

Need suggestions...

I am new to docker and trying out some examples. Questions i had regarding the docker backup and restore.

Do we need to backup only in tar ball format or is there any other format.
If i have huge db, does  backing up in tar ball will take good amount of time?
Do I need to stop my DB while backup so that data inconsistently might not occur.
If I stop will not my users looses there mind. Is there any alternative for backing up without actually stopping my DB server and still able to take complete backup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do a tarball back-up (I know the Docker documentation suggests this, but I always found that a bit strange). Instead look up the official documentation for backing-up your database and do that. That way you can take advantage of whatever tools and guarantees your DB provides for doing back-ups.

In some cases (e.g. Postgresql), a file-based back-up may be a viable option. But as you said, this may require temporarily stopping the database. In such cases you may be able to schedule the down-time so that it doesn't affect users. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Comment: I have found something interesting on snapshot technology and using copyonwrite which helps to take backup and downtime of db is minimized to only few seconds till it takes the snaphot, but the documentation is fine but i am not able to find any examples and confused for the same implementation for docker volumes. if there is  more info on this, it would be helpful.

Comment: I suspect Flocker from ClusterHQ can help: https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/. But I think you really need to experiment with the different options and see what works & how long it takes. Flocker uses ZFS, which does snapshots.

Comment: Note that Docker volumes are just using your host's filesystem; not CoW. If you have a filesystem such as BTRFS or ZFS, you may be able to do snapshots, which might be beneficial.

Comment: I need to upload the data on IBM swift. so cant use other fs

Comment: You've lost me. Surely uploading the data takes place after you've saved to the fs?

Answer (score 0):

Try helicopterizer.
Solution in Backup and Restore for Docker Container in the Cloud Providers!
https://github.com/frekele/helicopterizer